# iterate through file list of docx to extract and process table

Tags: python, docx

I am facing 3000 docx in several directories and subdirectories. I have to prepare a list which consists of the filename and extracted information from the tables in the docx. I have successfully added all the docx to the list `targets_in_dir` separating it from non relevant files.

Question : I would like to iterate through `targets_in_dir` extract all tables from the docx,

```
len_target =len(targets_in_dir)
file_processed=[]
string_tables=[]

for i in len_target:

    doc = docx.Document(targets_in_dir[i])
    file_processed.append(targets_ind[i])

    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                str.split('MANUFACTURER')
                string_tables.append(cell.text)
```

I get the error `'int' object is not iterable`

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-4847866a9234> in <module>
      4 string_tables=[]
      5 
----> 6 for i in len_target:
      7 
      8     doc = docx.Document(targets_in_dir[i])

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should post a reasonable amount of traceback, so we can further help you where it went wrong. but it looks like you are trying to iterate through `len_target` which sounds like you are iterating through a length of an object. `len` usually means it's an int, and your error is saying `'int' object is not iterable`, so I'd check there.

Comment: Also, what is `str` in `str.split('MANUFACTURER')` ?

Comment: @AlexKim traceback means the code with which I generated the list target_in_dir?

Comment: @michael I had hope to be able to cut the string at 'MANUFACTURER' which is a keyword using str.split

Comment: @NimrodEts tracebak is the output generated by python when an unhandled exception was raised. [Python Traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/)

Comment: @AlexKim added code and traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to iterate through `len_target = len(targets_in_dir)`, which is an int. Because `int` is not an iterable object, your for-loop fails.
You need to iterate through an iterable object for the `for` loop to work.
fixing it to

```py
for i in range(len_target):
    # do stuff
```

or

```py
for i in targets_in_dir:
    # do stuff
```

is a good place to start.

Also, your `file_processed.append(targets_ind[i])` has a typo.

Comment: thank you that solved the first part of my problem

Comment: @NimrodEts `file_processed.append(targets_ind[i])` has a typo. It looks like it should do what you want once you fix the typo.